# Java : Displaying time in UTC

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc

I am trying following piece of code using the Java Calendar API

```
class TimeIssue 
{
    public void showUTCTime(long millis, final String msg)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        System.out.println(msg + "(UTC):" + cal.getTime());
    }

    public void showLocalTime(long millis, final String msg)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        System.out.println(msg + "(LOCAL):" + cal.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long epochSec = 0;
        TimeIssue obj = new TimeIssue();

        obj.showUTCTime(epochSec, "EPOCH");
        obj.showLocalTime(epochSec, "EPOCH");
     }
}
```

When I execute this program, I get the output as ( My Time Zone is GMT+5:30)

```
EPOCH(UTC):Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
EPOCH(LOCAL):Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
```

I have 2 concerns here

- Should not the first line of the output be Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
- Why I am getting IST both the times even when I have set the time zone

Could you please suggest what am I missing here ?

Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Calendar.getTime()` method returns the `Date` object, which is just the number of milliseconds since epoch. Printing that instance invokes the `Date#toString()` method, which uses the system default timezone to format the date. Giving the Calendar instance a timezone, doesn't associate the resultant `Date` object with that timezone. In fact, `Date` object has no concept of timezones.

What you want is to format the date yourself using `DateFormat`, and set the timezone in that. Change your `UTC` method to this:

```
public void showUTCTime(long millis, final String msg) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(msg + "(UTC):" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the time zone by calling `obj.showUTCTime(epochSec, "EPOCH");` and it's saved after this. You need to set it again in `showLocalTime` to have the other time displayed in another time zone.

The first line of output is UTC 00:00:00 1970 in your time zone, that is 5:30

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742710/642706) is correct.

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

Working with date-time and time zones is much easier if you use a competent library. The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

## Joda-Time

Example code in Joda-Time 2.5. We instantiate a pair of DateTime objects that represent the same moment in the timeline of the Universe but as seen from two different wall-clock-times ([UTC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [India](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata)).

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTimeZone timeZoneKolkata = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneKolkata );
```